# OpenSSL: explicitly set start/end date using `openssl req`?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Using the `openssl req` tool, is it possible to explicitly specify the start and end dates on the certificate (eg, like the `-startdate` and `-enddate` options to `openssl ca`)?

I would like to create a certificate which is valid between a date in the past and a date in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`openssl req` creates a certificate request (CSR), not a certificate. It's up to the CA to decide the *notBefore* and *notAfter* dates (like any other attributes it's willing to issue) when it creates the certificate. The CSR format ([PKCS#10](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2132)) doesn't have any fields to put these dates.

Of course, if it's for a self-signed certificate, you can issue the certificate from your own CSR with the dates you want, using `openssl ca` (or by changing the configuration in the OpenSSL configuration file).

Comment: Aahh! This is it. Thanks. My problem was specifically with my CA's certificate (generated using `openssl req -new -x509 -keyout x.key -out x.crt`). I suppose the “correct” solution is to generate a CA (as above), create a new CSR (`req -new -key x.key -out x.csr`) then sign that CSR (`ca -in x.csr -out x_new.crt`) using the old certificate?

Comment: Yes, this should work. Strictly speaking, you're signing with the private key, and the issuer DN of the issued cert is just a piece of information (used to find the CA cert using its subject DN). There might be other ways, I'm not sure if `openssl ca` requires a `-cert` parameter, or if you could change the entire content of the cert to issue using the config file (and set the issuer to what you want). What you're suggesting should produce the correct result (a self-signed certificate with the tweaks you require) and is probably easier than digging into the openssl config options.

Comment: "you can issue the certificate from your own CSR with the dates you want" - and where is the example of that?

Comment: @mvmn I can't say I've tried recently, but the `-startdate` and `-enddate` options of the [OpenSSL `ca` command`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ca.html) look like a good place to start (as stated in the question). See this as well, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571337/372643