# OpenSSL Self-signed Root CA certificate: Set a start date

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm creating a little test CA with its own self-signed certificate using the following setup (using OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012). The issue I have is that if I look at the start date of the CAs own certificate, it creates it for tomorrow (and I'd like to use it today).

```
> openssl x509 -noout -startdate -enddate -in ~/my_little_ca/cacert.pem 
notBefore=Jan  2 16:05:52 2015 GMT
notAfter=Feb  1 16:05:52 2015 GMT
```

So I dug around a little because I had the same problem with certificates I signed using the CA. For these certificates I can set the start date using the `--startdate`, but I cannot see a similar option for the CAs root certificate. I've tried using `default_startdate` in the openssl config file used when generating the CA, but that seems to be ignored for some reason?

I create the CA as follows, which is basically just taken almost verbatim from "Network Security with OpenSSL" by Pravir Chandra et al, as shown further below.

**The command used is `req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -verbose`, but what I'd like to know is how do I set the startdate in this particular case when generating the root CAs certificate and private key?** Thank you in advance.

The full script to generate the CA is below:

```
MYDIR=$(pwd -P)
BASEDIR=~/enigma_ca


mkdir -pv $BASEDIR
cd $BASEDIR

mkdir -pv private
chmod g-rwx,o-rwx private
mkdir -pv certs
touch index.txt
echo '01' > serial

DEFAULT_STARTDATE=$(date +'%y%m01000000Z')

cat <<EOF >openssl.cnf
[ ca ]
default_ca = my_test_ca

[ my_test_ca ]
certificate       = $BASEDIR/cacert.pem
database          = $BASEDIR/index.txt
new_certs_dir     = $BASEDIR/certs
private_key       = $BASEDIR/private/cakey.pem
serial            = $BASEDIR/serial

default_crl_days  = 7
default_days      = 356
default_md        = md5
default_startdate = $DEFAULT_STARTDATE

policy            = my_test_ca_policy
x509_extensions   = certificate_extensions

[ my_test_ca_policy ]
commonName              = supplied
stateOrProvinceName     = supplied
countryName             = supplied
emailAddress            = supplied
organizationName        = supplied
organizationalUnitName  = optional

[ certificate_extensions ]
basicConstraints  = CA:false

[ req ]
default_bits      = 2048
default_keyfile   = $BASEDIR/private/cakey.pem
default_md        = md5
default_startdate = $DEFAULT_STARTDATE
default_days      = 356

prompt              = no
distinguished_name  = root_ca_distinguished_name
x509_extensions     = root_ca_extensions

[ root_ca_distinguished_name ]
commonName           = My Mini CA
stateOrProvinceName  = Hampshire
countryName          = UK
emailAddress         = ca@myminica.com
organizationName     = My Mini CA Ltd

[ root_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:true

EOF


OPENSSL_CONF=$BASEDIR/openssl.cnf
export OPENSSL_CONF

# Now generate self-signed certificate and generate key pair to go with it...
expect - <<EOF >> $MYDIR/ca_debug.txt
puts [concat "OPENSSL_CONF =" \$::env(OPENSSL_CONF)]
spawn openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -verbose
expect "PEM pass phrase:"
send "junk\r"
expect "PEM pass phrase:"
send "junk\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

Comment: Just notice. "default_md        = md5" is a hole in security. sha256 would be good.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use `openssl ca` with the `-selfsign` option to create your CA self-signed certificate.
This command allows to set spefic `-startdate` and `-enddate`

For instance:

- create a private key for your CA:

`openssl genrsa -out cakey.pem 2048`

- create a CSR for this key:

`openssl req -new -key cakey.pem -out ca.csr`

- create the self-signed certificate

`openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -selfsign -keyfile cakey.pem -startdate 20150214120000Z -enddate 20160214120000Z`

Comment: @Etienne Are those valid dates? The openssl docs state that -startdate and -enddate expect a date in YYMMDDHHMMSSZ which does not allow for 4 number year representation.

Comment: @Grasshopper the best way is to try it out :

```openssl ca  -config conf/caconfig.cnf  -startdate 20160107071311Z -enddate 20170106071311Z -batch -out server_cert_2048.pem -in server_cert_2048.pem.csr```  produces   ```err Certificate is to be certified until Jan  6 07:13:11 2017 GMT (363 days)``` : so Yes !

Comment: -startdate option is not supported

Comment: @ViktorMukhachev Not sure why you put is but we can still use '-startdate' option to set start date. Also we can set it in 'openssl.cnf' as 'default_startdate' so we dont need to mention explicitly every time we sign a certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace hardcoded zero to timeshift in seconds in line 843 of openssl apps/req.c

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/req.c#L843

```
if (!X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509ss),0)) goto end;
```

Example which creates request with date (now - 10 days):

```
if (!X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509ss),-10*24*3600)) goto end;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply :) Do you know if there is any way I can do this without having to recompile the command line tool?

Comment: Judging by req.c there is no such option. May be there exists some other unknown to me way to do it.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway... +1 for a good suggestion. I'll leave trying to compile the utility for later if i get really desperate :)

Comment: Could you achieve the same result with `libfaketime` that's available through `apt-get` in Ubuntu. `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" your_command_goes_here`